# Open SmsManager

Tags: android

Android:Hello,i am creating Sms aplication.I have ListView of all sms and i am trying if i click on any sms in listview it's open SmsManager where will be number of that sms.But there is unexpected end of aplication if i click on any message in listview.
Thank you for help.

There is source code:

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                SmsManager m = SmsManager.getDefault();
                Uri uriSMSURIs = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
                Cursor cc = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURIs, null, null, null, null);
                String destinationAddress  = cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndex("address"));
                m.sendTextMessage(destinationAddress , null, destinationAddress , null, null);


            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you get an exception when you run the app on a device connected to a PC/Mac and run "adb logcat"?

Comment: I didn't try it but i will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [debugging your app](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debug-tasks.html).

You should at least provide logcat (error log) and the line in code that produces the error/exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the index of the item which is clicked. What you are doing instead is fetching all rows for column "address"